# How do you find the catenary sag?

Tags: calculus, arc-length

[image]

The part I am confused on is how to find the catenary sag. I have done my research and I'm still confused. Can someone please explain how to do this on part E?

Given:

[image]

Comment: Is it 25 minus c to find the sag?

Comment: I am confused as to why you need help so fast.  Is it possible this is a test or homework problem?

Comment: Yes sir it is a homework project. I did the whole project without help, except Part E. I just need some quick clarifying on Part E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your equation is $y=a \cosh (\frac xa) +c$, the minimum is at $x=0$ and the poles are at $x=\pm 35$.  The sag is then $y(35)-y(0)$-the vertical distance between the support and the low point in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

25.8158 ended up being my answer for the sag.